# How to filter columns with ONLY specific values in R?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, dummy-variable

I have a dataset with some dummy variables that are coded as 1's and 2's instead of ones and zeros. The dataset is big, but I want to identify all of the columns with ONLY 1's, 2's and NA to change them to 1's and 0's.
I used 
`df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c('1', '2')))`
 but some variables are coded with numbers from 1 to 5 as well (or even more), so I want them out from the transformation.

Comment: is this character values and can it have only a 1, or 2 or NA value

Comment: @mariusagm It would be very helpful if you could provide a 'Reproducible' question. By giving a small table of dummy data it allows others to reproduce your answer(wrong or right) with the code You have shown. Otherwise everyone is shooting in the dark with no common pt of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to change those columns, `mutate_all` can be used

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         mutate_if(is.numeric, ~
          if(length(setdiff(unique(na.omit(.)), c(1, 2))) ==0) .-1 else .)
df2
#   col1 col2 grp       col3 col4
#1    1    0   a -0.5458808    5
#2    2    1   b  0.5365853    7
#3    3   NA   c  0.4196231    1
#4    4    0   d -0.5836272    2
#5    5    1   e  0.8474600    3
```

---

For selecting columns, `select` or `select_if` would be more useful than `filter`, as `filter` is for filtering the rows instead of the columnss

```
df1 %>%
     select_if(~ length(setdiff(unique(na.omit(.)), c(1, 2))) ==0)
#  col2
#1    1
#2    2
#3   NA
#4    1
#5    2
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = rep(c(1:2, NA), length.out = 5),
       grp = letters[1:5], col3 = rnorm(5), col4 = c(5, 7, 1, 2, 3) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep 1 as 1 and 2 as 0, we can use `mutate_if` to select only those columns which has value 1, 2 or `NA` and change them.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(~all(. %in% c(1, 2, NA)), ~as.integer(. == 1))
```